# Optimizing images on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a LOT of images from our WP site in S3. Around 45GB. Yep. It's a big old site. So I want to produce downsampled JPEG and a WEBP versions.

I have a tiny amount of AWS knowledge and this leads me to think it's a waste of computing power on our webservers to do the convert-on-upload or retrospective conversion of existing assets, and it'd be more sensible to do it in AWS Lambda, or something.

So, my question is... how do I create an AWS job that detects images coming up to S3, and creates a downsampled JPEG and WEBP version. And, second, is something similar in AWS' Batch functionality for all the existing folders?

To note, we use a fairly typical format for our `wp-content` folder: `/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/DATE`

Comment: "a waste of computing power on our webservers  to do the convert-on-upload or retrospective conversion of existing assets" 
It's pretty unlikely your webservers are tuned so well that they don't have extra resources to handle something like this.  I often see drastically overprovisioned webservers but rarely see very tightly provisioned webservers.  So if you're comfortable with the wordpress development space, why *not* use that same provisioned CPU to do the work?  you're already paying for it so it might be one of the cheaper options.

Comment: Be aware of [S3 Object Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-s3-object-lambda-use-your-code-to-process-data-as-it-is-being-retrieved-from-s3/). If you really don't want to proactively transform every image as it's uploaded to S3 or all existing images, then you might consider doing it on demand, and save the transformed images for later use. That will add some latency to an initial fetch of untransformed images, of course.

Comment: Related blog post: [Resize Images on the Fly with Amazon S3, AWS Lambda, and Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/).

Comment: @Jarmod Sorry, I should clarify, I want to transform images when they are uploaded to S3 from Wordpress (I use the WP Offload Plugin). Our site is high traffic and has lots of peaks, so I'm keen to keep the image serving side simpler and produce optimised versions on upload/ in a batch

Comment: Then the event-triggered Lambda function suggested in the answer below should be a consideration. Search for existing solutions as this is likely a common request.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with [Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html), every time an object is created in S3 you can trigger a Lambda function (or sns/sqs/event bridge) and create the webp version of the image with your code.